# Traversing CFG and calculating Running Average of Paths

Tags: llvm, graph-algorithm, control-flow-graph

I'm doing analysis on the LLVM machinecode CFG (CFG with Back-Edges removed), for each Instruction at the CFG I have attached at value (lets call it Cost), I  would like to calculate the running average of the CFG paths Total Cost with averaging window of W instructions in case that the running average pass some threshold (CostThreshould) then I would like to print the BasicBlock where this happened , for example calculate for every path on the CFG what is the running average cost over 1000 instructions, if the average grater than 7 at some path then print the last basic block of the path. 
**at this analysis I'm removing all the backedges of the graph so the CFG should be DAG**
is there an efficient way to calculate this?